# Which adapter am I missing for my washing mashine?

Tags: washing-machine, adapter

I got a new washing mashine from a friend. As we couldnt get of the tube, i had to buy a new one. Now it seems i am missing an Adapter.

Which Adapter do i need?

(I hope the questions is ok to ask here.)

Country: Germany. Online Shopping is possible.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unscrew the spigot from the tap and then the washing machine pipe will screw straight on to the 3/4 thread.

Edit based on comments:
This is a picture of a "normal" standard replacement hose. Do note both ends have plastic fittings which are standard. there are stainless wrapped versions but they are only rated to the same working pressure anyway.

Used these many times and the only time I ever saw one of the plastic nuts break was when it had a gorilla crush it with mole-grips, hand tight is more than ample.

[image]

Edit 2:
To help those who have not seen the pipe style with the electric valve, here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: now i feel very stupid and thankful at the same time. It seems to work, thanks!

Comment: OP Tlatwork note that you do not have to tighten the plastic fitting more than is necessary to seal. The rubber ring is the seal. Excessive tightening could introduce stress in the threaded plastic fitting and it could fail suddenly and without advance indication. In the US the ends of such hoses are steel or brass.

Comment: This looks like a new hose. In the US failing washing machine supply hoses are a major cause of residential flooding. The ends don't fail; the hoses age and rupture catastrophically.

Comment: @JimStewart the new devices come with hoses that have electric valves in the end that connects to the tap. can take a pic of one if you want.

Comment: Good call @SolarMike I thought that hose adapter was *part* of the spigot and was going to suggest a hose clamp.  :(

Comment: I'm seconding @JimStewart's recommendation to go buy better hoses.  Those plastic ends ... sooner or later someone overtightens one, it cracks, and a few weeks later it lets go.  Buy good hoses with steel reenforcement and metal fittings.

Comment: @Solar Mike, do these hoses with the electric valve shut off if a rupture is detected? I was not aware of that. I was aware of the mechanical safety hose brand FloodSafe. I replaced an elderly neighbor's old hoses with FloodSafe but he soon had me put in standard hoses because the filling rate was slow with the FloodSafe.

Comment: @JimStewart the water pipe has an outer cover sealed at the tap end and fixed to the machine at the other so there is likely a sensor at the machine end if water gets there. I don’t have a circuit diagram but they were also meant to shut-off if the machine leaked and never filled.

Comment: What brands and year models of clothes washers function with this new type hose? Does it plug into the washer or is it independent of the washer?

Comment: @JimStewart well the dishwasher I have just fitted is V-Zug but my "local" makes may not match yours.